# reduce margins for documentclass book?

Tags: margins

I am using documentclass book but want to shrink margins to 0.5 on each side and not have margin notes so the text can be wider.  Is there any way to request that or is that not legal for a book?

Comment: `0.5m`? `0.5in` etc.? `\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}` should work. Please consider that this might look weird, however

Comment: of course it's legal you can use `\setlength\textwidth{30cm}` if you wish. Probably best to use the `geometry` package to set all the parameters in a consistent way. Note however the default margins on A4 are not really wide to have marginal notes, they are wide as making the line length longer makes the text much harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

This does not look really nice -- it's hard to read, but setting `margin=0.5in` generates small margins.

I don't recommend this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in,nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I override margins for specific sections where i want different layouts, for example a cheat sheet?

Comment: Yes, with `\newgeometry` -- this will issue a page break however (but this no problem for a cheat sheet then). You should use `\savegeometry` and `\restoregeometry` before and after such special setups. See the documentation please